# Web console result is not comprehensible when switched to new OpenLayers library

Tags: openlayers

I'm using this library https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js initially and I was getting result in web console (ref below image)
[image]
However, when I started using this library https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js (ref the image)[image]
I'm getting result in not a convenient format.
I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Private property names ending with underscore have been minified.  It makes the code smaller but harder to debug.

Comment: @Mike I would say the size gain is negligible in the light of the big loss at the side of debugging. IMHO this was not a very wise decision, to put it mildly. I #@! it every day when I have to debug.

Comment: I'm having a nightmare. Earlier it was very easy to debug. Now I've to spend a lot of time to identify the problem

Comment: Is there no workaround?