# Beautify display of feature in console

Tags: openlayers

When I log a feature in my browser's console in order to get an overview of it, the feature is displayed in a hard-to-read format.

[image]

What is the reason behinde that? And can I beautify this somehow to have more readable property names?

Comment: See comments to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416701/web-console-result-is-not-comprehensible-when-switched-to-new-openlayers-library

Comment: Is there something like a cdn with an ol-debug.js file that is not minified/uglified?

Comment: No, not any more.

Comment: Is there any other way to make debugging with ol6 easier? It seems quite a hassle to me.

Comment: Not out of the box. You have to use node.js developing environment for that, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html