# Log OpenLayers objects to the console - not really readable

Tags: openlayers

When I log a feature in OpenLayers to the console, the output looks ugly. instead of proper field names, I see fields  called 'A', 'C', 'O' and so on. How can I make a prettier log that corresponds to the API (and what is the reason for this weird fact)?

The same applies to other OpenLayers objects as well.

Comment: See comments to question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416701/web-console-result-is-not-comprehensible-when-switched-to-new-openlayers-library